# Запуск программы на пайтон через GPU

Tags: python, cuda, pytorch, cpu, gpu

Я запускаю программу, работающую на основе библиотеки **easyocr**, при каждом запуске программа выдает в консоль информацию:

> Neither CUDA nor MPS are available - defaulting to CPU.

<sup>Примечание: Этот модуль работает намного быстрее с графическим процессором.</sup>

Теперь я пытаюсь запустить программу через gpu, я установил cuda v.11.8, но при запуске программы `print(f"CUDA version: {torch.version.cuda}")`:

```python
if torch.cuda.is_available(): 
    device = torch.device('cuda') 
    print('Using GPU.') 
else: 
    device = torch.device('cpu') 
    print('Using CPU.')
```

Выдает:

```
CUDA version: None Using CPU.
```

Подскажите, что нужно исправить, для того, чтобы python видел установленную версию cuda, а также запускал программу через **gpu**.

Comment: Cuda только для игровых и специальных видеокарт Nvidia

Comment: Cuda должна поддерживаться вашей видеокартой на аппаратном уровне.

Comment: если карта amd, то там не cuda а opencl